# CSS :before pseudo element displays one but not both on separate elements

Tags: html, css, wordpress, font-awesome

I'm trying to display some FA icons before some items in WordPress sidebar widgets & I've had mixed success with this. I'm targeting two separate items & one or the other will display the icon but not both. In the code given, the first instance is the one being displayed.

I'd appreciate any feedback! Here's my CSS:

```css
    #recent-comments-2 li,
    .widget_recent_entries li {
      padding-left: 1.2em;
      margin-bottom: 7px;
    }
    .widget_recent_entries li:before {
      font-family: FontAwesome;
      content: "\f040";
      display: inline-block;
      width: 1.2em;
      margin-left: -1.2em;
    }
    #recent-comments-2 li:before {
      font-family: FontAwesome;
      content: "\f075";
      display: inline-block;
      width: 1.2em;
      margin-left: -1.2em;
    }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<li id="recent-posts-2" class="widget-container widget_recent_entries">
  <h3 class="widget-title">Recent Posts</h3> 
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">16OCT15</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">15OCT15</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">14OCT15</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">13OCT15</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>

<li id="recent-comments-2" class="widget-container widget_recent_comments">
  <h3 class="widget-title">Recent Comments</h3>
  <ul id="recentcomments">
    <li class="recentcomments"><span class="comment-author-link">Bob</span> on <a href="#">16OCT15</a>
    </li>
    <li class="recentcomments"><span class="comment-author-link">Bill</span> on <a href="#">16OCT15</a>
    </li>
    <li class="recentcomments"><span class="comment-author-link">Bob</span> on <a href="#">15OCT15</a>
    </li>
    <li class="recentcomments"><span class="comment-author-link">Bill</span> on <a href="#">15OCT15</a>
    </li>
    <li class="recentcomments"><span class="comment-author-link">Bill</span> on <a href="#">Random Post</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: Can you show us your markup html...or make a jsfiddle

Comment: We definitely need to see the HTML. Please edit your question and use the "Code Snippet" function here, rather than using JSFiddle.

Comment: Ok folks - HTML added!

Comment: @JeffW , I reformatted your code as a "snippet" so that we could run it. Correct me if I'm wrong...but it looks like it's working?

Comment: Aye, it works here but for some reason it's not doing so on the theme ... bugger, this means I'm going to have to troll through all of my CSS.  If it's not making IE behave, it's the neighbors.  Thanks for having a look, I'll post what I find.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working but I'm still not sure why - simply separating the two rules with another rule in between them made it work.  There are no conflicting CSS rules with any of this but this is what resolved my issue.  This is how it was resolved:

```
#recent-comments-2 li,
.widget_recent_entries li  {
    padding-left: 1.2em;
    margin-bottom: 7px;
}

.widget_recent_entries li:before {
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    content: "\f040";
    display: inline-block;
    width: 1.2em;
    margin-left: -1.2em; 
}​

#footer {
    position: relative;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    height: auto;
    clear:both;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #242424;
    padding-top: 5px;
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.15);
    box-shadow: 0 0 7px #323232;
    margin-top: 35px;
    } 

#recent-comments-2 li:before {
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    content: "\f075";
    display: inline-block;
    width: 1.2em;
    margin-left: -1.2em;
}​
```